# Differentiating host name of websites

Tags: web, ip-address, hostname, domain-name

I am confused if the mentioned below two web links can be said having same host name or different.
As both links carry same domain names but different local names, Meanwhile, both have different IP addresses.

https://trek.nasa.gov/moon/index.html

https://www.nasa.gov/topics/technology/index.html

Any explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They are domain/subdomain names, which is a different concept to hostname. In fact each subdomain points to a different machines (hosts), first one to lmmp.jpl.nasa.gov, second one to https-87-248-214-97.lon.llnw.net.